# Show images in list from typescript array

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework

I have to show all images that are coming from a server as base64 strings. Thereofre I have created an array of images like this:

```
for (let i in json) {
        this.imageArray.push({
            imageUrl: json[i].datas
        })
     }
```

Now, I am trying to show these images from array in html file:

```
<ion-list no-lines>
   <ion-item *ngFor="let item of imageArray">
      <ion-img src="data:image/*;base64,{{item.imageUrl}}"></ion-img>
   </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

But the images are not shown.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to wrote the following code

```
<ion-list [virtualScroll]="imageArray">

  <ion-item *virtualItem="let item">
    <ion-img src="data:image/*;base64,{{item.imageUrl}}" style="height: 300px; width: 100%;"></ion-img>
  </ion-item>

</ion-list>
```

and in .ts file

```
 for (let i in json) {
        this.imageArray.push({
          imageUrl: json[i].datas
        })
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
<ion-img *ngIf="item.imageUrl" [src]="'data:image/*;base64,'+item.imageUrl"></ion-img>
```

Comment: i have an error like this
Error: Quotes are not supported for evaluation!
        Statement: image/*;base64,+item.imageUrl located at ng:///home/GMS/src/pages/exerciseimage/exerciseimage.html@11:17

Comment: <ion-img [src]="'data:image/*;base64,'+item.imageUrl"></ion-img>

Comment: look images are come from the code that i have written in the question but the problem is that the image are come one time out of 10 time..
i hope you understand well

Comment: then you need to use ngIF

Comment: how to do it can you please suggest me??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157857/discussion-between-sajeetharan-and-mustafa-lokhanwala).